# Code not working for copying data from a selected file into the current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

my following code was working previously but not generates error 13

```
Sub Get_Plate_A_Data()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your raw data file to import",         FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")

If FileToOpen <> False Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("C126:AP221").Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("C39").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
OpenBook.Close False

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I have tried changing the sheet names to no success

Comment: If the sheet is named "Sheet1", then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. If its codename is `Sheet1`, then just `Sheet1.Range("39")...`. If you want the first worksheet, then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`.